# How to restore Evolution' mails

Tags: 11.04, evolution, restore

I probably made a big mistake a couple days ago - tried Gnome 3 on my Natty 11.04 laptop :)

As a result, the system becomes unusable and I was forced to reinstall Natty. I did a fresh installation with the formatting of my home partition (usually I do that way). The only one thing what I care about it's my mails (Evolution).

Usually, I make a copy of `.local/share/evolution/` directory, and then after installation just copies it into the same directory - it was absolutely enough for me before (I did it at least 4 times).

But this time I've got an error from Evolution - `Unable to retrieve message`

As far as I understood Gnome 3 had changed the structure of Nautilus and moved Evolution contents into another place :(

Is there any chance to get my emails back into Evolution somehow?

I would be very appreciated for help

[image: Evolution_unable_to_retrieve_message]

EDIT: Some additional info to my question - I have Hotmail account, so the messages retrieve by Evolution directly from MSN server (POP), and I don't leave the copies of the emails on the server. So, the only place where messages are resists - it's my laptop

EDIT 2: Here you can see output of id command :

> uid=1000(justas) gid=1000(justas)
>   groups=1000(justas),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),46(plugdev),112(lpadmin),120(admin),122>(sambashare)

and output of ls -nd /home/justas/.local/share/evolution command :

> drwx------ 8 1000 1000 4096 2011-09-30 00:37 /home/justas/.local/share/evolution

Comment: Please post output of following two commands: `id` and `ls -nd /home/justas/.local/share/evolution`

Comment: OK, I'll do that this evening . My laptop is not available for me at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the permissions might be wrong. You could try

```
sudo chown -R justas:justas /home/justas/.local
```

to change ownership of that whole subtree back to you. If that doesn't do it, you can change the permissions of all files and directories to allow you to read them by:

```
chmod -R u+r /home/justas/.local
find /home/justas/.local -type d -exec chmod u+x \{\} \+
```

The first command adds the `read` permission to everything in that subtree, the second command searches for all directories and adds the `execute` permission, allowing you to change into it.